# Troubles with assigning .src for a thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, src, classname

*I'm very much a beginner at Javascript, so keep that in mind for any small inefficiencies in my code.*

I'm attempting to set the IDs of a group of divs "galleryboxes" (that are inside a another div, "galleryimages") to be increasing increments, ie. picture1, picture2, etc.

Inside each div (from 'galleryboxes') is one picture each; in the second line of my for loop I'm attempting to do the same as to the div above and give them an id. I then want to use this picture to make a thumbnail from it (posted to the div 'gallery').

```
var galleryimages = document.getElementById("galleryimages");
var galleryboxes = galleryimages.getElementsByTagName("div");

var k = 1;
var thumbimage = document.createElement("img");

for (var i = 0; i < galleryboxes.length; i++) {
    galleryboxes[i].id = "item" + k;
    galleryboxes[i].getElementsByTagName("img").id = "picture" + k;
    thumbimage.src = document.getElementById("picture" + k).src;
    document.getElementById("gallery").appendChild(thumbimage);
    //thumbimage.className = "thumbnail";
    k++;
}
```

Unforunately, when I 'appendChild', it just says it can't read the .src property of null. I've tried re-arranging a few things, but I can't get just the image to make a thumbnail from it. I'm fairly sure I've assigned the ID to the right item...

Along with that, my commented out code is trying to assign the new thumbnail a class, which for the few times I've gotten close to getting this to work didn't seem to work itself. Is there any clear thing wrong there?

Comment: `galleryboxes[i].getElementsByTagName("img").id = "picture" + k;` doesn't make sense. `getElementsByTagName("img")` returns a nodeList, which is an Array-like object containing a referece to the `img`s in `galleryboxes[i]`. Hence I think you'll need to iterate over the nodeList, and set the `id`s in that iteration loop.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be exactly my problem... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two problems:

1) you create only 1 thumbimage, but iterate through an array of galleryboxes

2) `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements ([NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList)), and you set the `.id` of the NodeList. If you are sure there is exactly 1 img, use `getElementsByTagName()[0]`.

Comment: Maybe it would be fair also to tell OP, that `appendChild()` will move the newly created element from `thumbimage` to the DOM, and after appending `thumbimage` will be `null`.

Comment: The thumbimage and appendChild issues I already understood, but the second tagname/nodelist idea I didn't know, thanks!